# Camera orientation issue in Android

Tags: android, orientation, android-camera-intent

I am building an application that uses camera to take pictures. Here is my source code to do this:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            imageFileName);
imageFilePath = file.getPath();
Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
// Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVITY_NATIVE_CAMERA_AQUIRE);
```

On `onActivityResult()` method, I use `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()` to pickup the image.

When I run my application on Nexus one, it runs well. But when I run on Samsung Galaxy S or HTC Inspire 4G, the image's direction is not correct.

- Capture with portrait mode, the real image (save on SD card) always rotates 90 degree.

[image: image preview after shot] [image: real image on SD card]

Image preview after shot --------- Real image on SD card

- Capture with landscape mode, all things are good.

[image: Image preview after shot] [image: Real image on SD card]

Image preview after shot --------- Real image on SD card

Comment: setRotation(90) did work for me in Samsung Galaxy Nexus, while it didn't rotate the image in Xperia S.

Comment: can anyone help me with this?  i have same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28379130/how-to-set-camera-image-orientation/28379610?noredirect=1#comment45100385_28379610

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14066038/why-image-captured-using-camera-intent-gets-rotated-on-some-devices-in-android

Comment: Answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14066038/why-image-captured-using-camera-intent-gets-rotated-on-some-devices-in-android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does an image captured using camera intent gets rotated on some devices on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14066038/why-does-an-image-captured-using-camera-intent-gets-rotated-on-some-devices-on-a)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Since you're not writing your own camera, I think it boils down to this:

some devices rotate the image before saving it, while others simply add the orientation tag in the photo's exif data.

I'd recommend checking the photo's exif data and looking particularly for

```
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(SourceFileName); // Since API Level 5
String exifOrientation = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION);
```

Since the photo is displaying correctly in your app, i'm not sure where the problem is, but this should definitely set you on the right path!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on some devices, it returns 0 for all orientations.. I know it happens on Galaxy S Infuse and Sony Xperia Arc, and S II.. Interesting thing here is that when these same images are selected from gallery, the content provider has the proper orientation value.. Any ideas?

Comment: here sourcefilename actually the entire file path

Comment: @TolgaE You are right. It returns 0 for some devices including DroidX. I am currently working on a solution. Not sure if it's going to work.

Comment: @Abhijit Yes I tried to solve this (opened ticket with Android and so on) And i think I found a reasonable solution to handle both phones with proper and faulty orientation information. Check out my detailed answer I posted to my own question here; http://stackoverflow.com/a/8864367/137404

Comment: @ramz I tried this solution to find. but it is returning 0 for all orientations. Do you have any idea why it is returning 0 for all orientation.

Comment: @Abhijit, have u got the solution, if yes,could u please share it?

Comment: @CrazyLearner sorry bro, this was so long ago that I can't even recall. I will let you know if I find something.

Comment: The reason for this solution not working is sometimes a wrong "path" used in ExifInterface constructor. Mostly on KitKat. See here, how to get the right path: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20559175/690777

Comment: It always returns 0 (ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED) on my Samsung Galaxy S4...

Comment: Struggled for a while with rotation method since on some device when tacking photo in portrait mode simple rotation makes image stretched. The solution found was: `code 
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postTranslate(-width / 2, -height / 2);
        matrix.postRotate(angle);
        matrix.postTranslate(width / 2, height / 2); `

Comment: full & correct answer present here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069122/camera-orientation-issue-in-android/38047313#38047313

Comment: At the case of adding orientation tag in the photo's exif data, the problem is when i try to edit image, the created bitmap is rotated. I have to look the exif data and rotate it into original. it's taking some time and also annoying.

Answer (score 28):

I used this to correct the orientation:

```
public void fixOrientation() {
    if (mBitmap.getWidth() > mBitmap.getHeight()) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(90);
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mBitmap , 0, 0, mBitmap.getWidth(), mBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    }
}
```

If the width of the Bitmap is greater than the height, the returned image is in landscape, so I rotate it 90 degrees.

Comment: What if the image was actually *taken* in landscape? Your code will still rotate it. This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: My application forces portrait, so that isn't an issue.  I only included this here an alternative solution to the problem.

Comment: But if the application forces portrait you still can take a landscape picture (width > height) and it will be rotated... It's at least what I'm getting setting screenOrientation="portrait" for everything... camera still can take landscape pics.

Comment: full & correct answer present here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069122/camera-orientation-issue-in-android/38047313#38047313

Answer (score 22):

There are two things needed:

1. Camera preview need the same as your rotation. Set this by `camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);`
2. Save the picture captured as your camera preview.
   Do this via `Camera.Parameters`.

   ```
    int mRotation = getCameraDisplayOrientation();

    Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();

    parameters.setRotation(mRotation); //set rotation to save the picture

    camera.setDisplayOrientation(result); //set the rotation for preview camera

    camera.setParameters(parameters);
   ```

Comment: this is it! Camera.parameters is really convenient to save snapshots without rendering to an intermediate bitmap

Comment: Please mark this as the easiest answer! This do the job! Very happy about this easy solution

Comment: If this snippet is taken as is, we could just say `parameters.setRotation(result)`, no?

Comment: This assumes you are using the Camera class directly, you aren't able to specify the same options when you are using the ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent.

Comment: What is result and getCameraDisplayOrientation()?

Answer (score 10):

```
            int rotate = 0;
            try {
                File imageFile = new File(sourcepath);
                ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(
                        imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
                int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                        ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                        ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

                switch (orientation) {
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                    rotate = 270;
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                    rotate = 180;
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                    rotate = 90;
                    break;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(rotate);
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap , 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```

Comment: it would be helpful to have some explanation what your code is doing, and how it is doing things differently than other answers (the question is after all already quite old, and the other answers therefore probably quite mature).

Answer (score 8):

Another option is to rotate the bitmap in the result screen like this:

```
ImageView img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.refresh);
// Getting width & height of the given image.
int w = bmp.getWidth();
int h = bmp.getHeight();
// Setting post rotate to 90
Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
mtx.postRotate(90);
// Rotating Bitmap
Bitmap rotatedBMP = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, true);
BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable(rotatedBMP);

img.setImageDrawable(bmd);
```

Comment: This approach won't work, as it also rotates images from devices that handles orientation properly.

Comment: full & correct answer present here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069122/camera-orientation-issue-in-android/38047313#38047313

Answer (score 3):

I have also this type of same problem for some device:

```
private void rotateImage(final String path) {

    Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Conasants.bm1, 1000,
            700, true);
    Bitmap rotatedBitmap = null;
    try {
        ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(path);
        int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        switch (orientation) {
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
            matrix.postRotate(90);
            rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0,
                    scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(),
                    matrix, true);
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
            matrix.postRotate(180);
            rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0,
                    scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(),
                    matrix, true);
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
            matrix.postRotate(270);
            rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0,
                    scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(),
                    matrix, true);
            break;
        default:
            rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0,
                    scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(),
                    matrix, true);
            break;
        }
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    cropImage.setImageBitmap(rotatedBitmap);
    rotatedBitmap = null;
    Conasants.bm1 = null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way :
static Uri image_uri;
static  Bitmap taken_image=null;

```
            image_uri=fileUri; // file where image has been saved

      taken_image=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image_uri.getPath());
      try
        {
            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(image_uri.getPath()); 

            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);


            switch(orientation) {
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                    taken_image=decodeScaledBitmapFromSdCard(image_uri.getPath(), 200, 200);
                    RotateBitmap(taken_image, 90);
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                    taken_image=decodeScaledBitmapFromSdCard(image_uri.getPath(), 200, 200);
                    RotateBitmap(taken_image, 180);

                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                    taken_image=decodeScaledBitmapFromSdCard(image_uri.getPath(), 200, 200);
                    RotateBitmap(taken_image, 270);

                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
                    taken_image=decodeScaledBitmapFromSdCard(image_uri.getPath(), 200, 200);
                    RotateBitmap(taken_image, 0);

                    break;
            }

        }
        catch (OutOfMemoryError e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),e+"\"memory exception occured\"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }



public Bitmap RotateBitmap(Bitmap source, float angle) {
      Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
      matrix.postRotate(angle);

      round_Image = source;
      round_Image = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(),   source.getHeight(), matrix, true);


  return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

No more checking the photo's exif data. Go easy with **Glide**.

Google introduced us an Image Loader Library for Android developed by bumptech named **Glide** as a library that recommended by Google. It has been used in many Google open source projects till now including Google I/O 2014 official application.

Ex : Glide.with(context).load(uri).into(imageview);

For more : https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Answer (score 1):

```
public void setCameraPicOrientation(){
        int rotate = 0;
        try {
            File imageFile = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(
                    imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                    ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                    ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

            switch (orientation) {
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                    rotate = 270;
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                    rotate = 180;
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                    rotate = 90;
                    break;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(rotate);
        int targetW = 640;
        int targetH = 640;

        /* Get the size of the image */
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
        int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
        int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

        /* Figure out which way needs to be reduced less */
        int scaleFactor = 1;
        if ((targetW > 0) || (targetH > 0)) {
            scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH);
        }

        /* Set bitmap options to scale the image decode target */
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
        bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

        /* Decode the JPEG file into a Bitmap */
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
        bitmap= Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap , 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
            /* Associate the Bitmap to the ImageView */
      imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
```

Hope this will help!! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static  int mOrientation =  1;
    
    OrientationEventListener myOrientationEventListener;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.takephoto);
        
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        
        
        myOrientationEventListener
        = new OrientationEventListener(getApplicationContext()) {
            
            @Override
            public void onOrientationChanged(int o) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(!isTablet(getApplicationContext()))
                {
                    if(o<=285 && o>=80)
                        mOrientation = 2;
                    else
                        mOrientation = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    if(o<=285 && o>=80)
                        mOrientation = 1;
                    else
                        mOrientation = 2;
                }
                
            }
        };
        
        myOrientationEventListener.enable();
        
    }
    
    
    
    public static boolean isTablet(Context context) {
        return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
                & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK)
                >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE;
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just encounter the same issue here, the code snippet below works for me:

```
private static final String[] CONTENT_ORIENTATION = new String[] {
        MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION
};

static int getExifOrientation(ContentResolver contentResolver, Uri uri) {
    Cursor cursor = null;

    try {
        cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, CONTENT_ORIENTATION, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null || !cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            return 0;
        }
        return cursor.getInt(0);
    } catch (RuntimeException ignored) {
        // If the orientation column doesn't exist, assume no rotation.
        return 0;
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in surfaceChanged callback:

```
Camera.Parameters parameters=mCamera.getParameters();
if(this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
    parameters.setRotation(90);
}else{
    parameters.setRotation(0);
}
mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
```

Answer (score 0):

//button click

```
btnCamera.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

                try {
                    ContentValues values;
                    values = new ContentValues();
                    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "New Picture");
                    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "From your Camera");
                    imageUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(
                            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
                }catch (Exception e){}

            });
```

//onActivityResult method

```
   if (requestCode==CAMERA_REQUEST){
        try {
            if (imageUri!=null) {
                path = String.valueOf(new File(FilePath.getPath(context, imageUri)));
                   }  
        }catch (Exception e){
            toast("please try again "+e.getMessage());
            Log.e("image error",e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

//create a class filepath

public class FilePath {

```
public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

    // check here to KITKAT or new version
    final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

    // DocumentProvider
    if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {

        // ExternalStorageProvider
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
                        + split[1];
            }
        }
        // DownloadsProvider
        else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"),
                    Long.valueOf(id));

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
        }
        // MediaProvider
        else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            Uri contentUri = null;
            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }

            final String selection = "_id=?";
            final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { split[1] };

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection,
                    selectionArgs);
        }
    }
    // MediaStore (and general)
    else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

        // Return the remote address
        if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
            return uri.getLastPathSegment();

        return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
    }
    // File
    else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * Get the value of the data column for this Uri. This is useful for
 * MediaStore Uris, and other file-based ContentProviders.
 *
 * @param context
 *            The context.
 * @param uri
 *            The Uri to query.
 * @param selection
 *            (Optional) Filter used in the query.
 * @param selectionArgs
 *            (Optional) Selection arguments used in the query.
 * @return The value of the _data column, which is typically a file path.
 */
public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri,
                                   String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {

    Cursor cursor = null;
    final String column = "_data";
    final String[] projection = { column };

    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection,
                selection, selectionArgs, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
            return cursor.getString(index);
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * @param uri
 *            The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
 */
public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri
            .getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri
 *            The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
 */
public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri
            .getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri
 *            The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
 */
public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri
            .getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri
 *            The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is Google Photos.
 */
public static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
    return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri
            .getAuthority());
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

The code is functionally for landscape and portrait
@frontCameraID = variable got it the method classic for show camera wanted

```
@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    
    if(holder.getSurface() == null) {
        return;
    }
    try{
        camera.stopPreview();
    } catch (Exception e){
    }

    try{

        int orientation = getDisplayOrientation(frontCameraID);

        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
        if (parameters.getSupportedFocusModes().contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE)) {
            parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
        }

        parameters.setRotation(rotationPicture);
        camera.setParameters(parameters);
        camera.setDisplayOrientation(orientation);
        camera.startPreview();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("ERROR", "Camera error changed: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Method for get orientation y rotation to save picture and display orientation
@result = orientation on the preview view of camera
@rotationPicture = rotation necessary to save picture correctly

```
private int getDisplayOrientation(int cameraId) {

    android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info = new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
    android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
    int rotation = ((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    int degrees = 0;
    switch (rotation) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0: degrees = 0; break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_90: degrees = 90; break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_180: degrees = 180; break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_270: degrees = 270; break;
    }

    int result;
    if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
        result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
        result = (360 - result) % 360;
        rotationPicture = (360 - result) % 360;
    } else {
        result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
        rotationPicture = result;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

**two One line solutions using Picasso and glide library**

After spending a lot of time with a lot of solutions for image rotation problem I finally found two simple solutions. We don't need to do any additional works. Picasso and Glide are a very powerful library for handling images in your app includes. It will read image EXIF data and auto-rotates the images.

**Using glide library**  https://github.com/bumptech/glide

```
Glide.with(this).load("http url or sdcard url").into(imgageView);
```

**Using Picasso library** https://github.com/square/picasso

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http url or sdcard url").into(imageView);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please refrain from asking for upvotes: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194061/is-it-acceptable-to-ask-for-upvote-accept-in-an-answer-when-submitting-it