# android front and back camera captured picture orientation issue, rotated in a wrong way

Tags: android, camera, orientation, nexus-s

I have a camera app in portrait mode which takes pictures from both front and back end cameras.The issue is like the captured images are rotated in a wrong way...

For preview i have used the following code....

```
    Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info = new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
        android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(defaultCameraId, info);
        int rotation = this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
                .getRotation();
        if (Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK) >= 8) {

            int degrees = 0;
            switch (rotation) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                degrees = 0;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                degrees = 90;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                degrees = 180;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                degrees = 270;
                break;
            }
            int result;
            if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
                result = (360 - result) % 360; // compensate the mirror
            } else { // back-facing
                result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
            }

            camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);

        } else {
            parameters.set("orientation", "portrait");
        }

        camera.setParameters(parameters);
```

But the captured images are rotated in a wrong way.i have also tried to rotate the captured image using `matrix.postRotate(bitmap)`.That too doesn't work in some devices like nexus..I tried EXIF also.But here i have url instead of filepath.That doesn't work as well. can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can refer below code.

```
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(SourceFileName);     //Since API Level 5

String exifOrientation = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION);
```

And also refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/6124375/1441666

Comment: I'm getting url of that image..How can i convert into filename ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use this to get orientation from a `Uri`

```
                    String filePath = mImageUri.getPath();
                if (filePath != null) {
                    rotation = -1;
                        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(filePath); // Since
                                                                            // API
                                                                            // Level
                                                                            // 5
                        rotation = Integer.parseInt(exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION));
                        // //Log.v("roation",
                        // exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION));
                    }

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Internal error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
            }
```

And as note rotation '3 = 180, 6 = 90, 8 = 270'

Comment: You can adapt to your need I suppose, not sure if it will solve the problem you are having though.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using the following code for this:

```
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(getUriPath(uri));
int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
```

getUriPath:

```
public String getUriPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null,
            null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(projection[0]);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String filePath = cursor.getString(column_index);
        cursor.close();
        return filePath;
    } else
        return null;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

try this code snippet

```
try {

    ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(filePath);
    orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+orientation, 1).show();
    Log.v("log", "ort is "+orientation);

    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and then rotate the matrix as per orientation you get

```
if (orientation==6)
{
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(90);
    bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), matrix, true);
}
else if (orientation==8)
{
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(270);
    bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), matrix, true);
}

else if (orientation==3)
{
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(180);
    bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), matrix, true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the selected answer just gives the the possible rotation that may have been saved in EXIF header. in several cases camera doesn't set "ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION" attribute in EXIFHeader so it will be 0(ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED). and event if it is set it will be true in only one case/orientation when the picture is taken. you have to manually set rotation in camera parameters using setRotation() method. the documentation of  setRotation() is very clear and also explains how to calculate rotation with consideration of device rotation and camera sensor orientation(usually landscape).

so check out setRotation() method . thats what you need to change.