# Camera preview is in portrait mode but image captured is rotated

Tags: android, android-camera

I am trying to capture a photo using the camera. The preview by default was in landscape mode which i could change it to portrait mode using

```
    setCameraDisplayOrientation(this,1,  mCamera);
    public static void setCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity,
         int cameraId, android.hardware.Camera camera) {
     android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info =
             new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
     android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
     int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
             .getRotation();
     int degrees = 0;
     switch (rotation) {
         case Surface.ROTATION_0: degrees = 0; break;
         case Surface.ROTATION_90: degrees = 90; break;
         case Surface.ROTATION_180: degrees = 180; break;
         case Surface.ROTATION_270: degrees = 270; break;
     }

     int result;
     if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
         result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
         result = (360 - result) % 360;  // compensate the mirror
     } else {  // back-facing
         result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
     }
     camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
 }
```

The image captured is stored under a folder myImages. But the images is rotated. (look's like the image is captured in landscape mode)

So how can i rotate the image captured and save the same?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1; 
ImageView imageView;
Button b;
private Camera mCamera;
private CameraPreview mPreview;
private Bitmap bitmap;
private PictureCallback mPicture;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    boolean check =checkCameraHardware(MainActivity.this);
    if(check)
    {
         mCamera = getCameraInstance();

        // mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
         setCameraDisplayOrientation(this,
                 1,  mCamera);//requires min sdk 9
    }
    // Create an instance of Camera
    mPicture = new PictureCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

            File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyImages");
            if(!imagesFolder.exists())
            imagesFolder.mkdirs();   
            File pictureFile = new File(imagesFolder, "image.jpg");

            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);

                System.out.println("hello");
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.d("No File", "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    };

    // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
    mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
    FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    preview.addView(mPreview);
     b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
     b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
      {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
                 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Called",1000).show();

        }

      });
  }
 public static void setCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity,
         int cameraId, android.hardware.Camera camera) {
     android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info =
             new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
     android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
     int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
             .getRotation();
     int degrees = 0;
     switch (rotation) {
         case Surface.ROTATION_0: degrees = 0; break;
         case Surface.ROTATION_90: degrees = 90; break;
         case Surface.ROTATION_180: degrees = 180; break;
         case Surface.ROTATION_270: degrees = 270; break;
     }

     int result;
     if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
         result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
         result = (360 - result) % 360;  // compensate the mirror
     } else {  // back-facing
         result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
     }
     camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
 }
private boolean checkCameraHardware(Context context) {
    if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)){
        // this device has a camera
         Toast.makeText(this, "Phone has camera", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    } else {
        // no camera on this device
         Toast.makeText(this, "Phone has no camera", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return false;
    }
}
public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
    }
    return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
}


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    mCamera.release();
}
  }
```

The CameraPreview class is the same from the developer site http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html

Note: I am using the back camera not the front facing camera.

Comment: I answer similar question on another post http://stackoverflow.com/a/34323194/4847767

Answer (score 35):

I faced the same problem when taking photo from camera in portrait mode. Below lines of code solved my problem:

```
public static void setCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity, int cameraId, android.hardware.Camera camera) {
    android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info = new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
    android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
    int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    int degrees = 0;
    switch (rotation) {
    case Surface.ROTATION_0:
            degrees = 0;
            break;
    case Surface.ROTATION_90:
            degrees = 90;
            break;
    case Surface.ROTATION_180:
            degrees = 180;
            break;
    case Surface.ROTATION_270:
            degrees = 270;
            break;
    }

    int result;
    if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
            result = (360 - result) % 360; // compensate the mirror
    } else { // back-facing
            result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
    }
    camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
}
```

Call `setCameraDisplayOrientation()` method in surfaceCreated callback as the following:

```
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    camera = Camera.open();
    setCameraDisplayOrientation(getActivity(), CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK, camera);
}
```

I had to rotate the image in Camera `onPictureTaken()` callback:

```
camera.takePicture(null, null, new PictureCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

            if (data != null) {
                int screenWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
                int screenHeight = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
                Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, (data != null) ? data.length : 0);

                if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
                    // Notice that width and height are reversed
                    Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, screenHeight, screenWidth, true);
                    int w = scaled.getWidth();
                    int h = scaled.getHeight();
                    // Setting post rotate to 90
                    Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
                    mtx.postRotate(90);
                    // Rotating Bitmap
                    bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaled, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, true);
                }else{// LANDSCAPE MODE
                    //No need to reverse width and height
                    Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, screenWidth,screenHeight , true);
                    bm=scaled;
                }
                photoPreview.setImageBitmap(bm);
            }
            isImageCaptured = true;
            photoPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            surfaceView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
});
```

Comment: I also applied same solution for the same problem, but at starting i got our of memory Error. Then i stored compressed bitmap to get rid of this situation. but This process is very slow while creating new bitmap my screen hold. for half minute my app stuck into a black screen. do u have any solution of it

Comment: @HemantG can u pls tell me where should i need to write Orientation code as my picture is rotated in case of only front camera ......

Comment: @HemantG Everything is cool in your solution and it will definitely work. You are scaling down the bitmap before rotation to avoid OutOfMemory Exception. If we save  this new bitmap then it will scaled down version of original bitmap. I want to save the bitmap with original resolution without getting OutOfMemory exception. How can I do this? Why is the camera giving rotated image even if the preview is portrait? Please help me out.

Comment: I am getting the image rotated from back camera by this code but in font camera the image is rotated by 180 degree. what should i do for that.

Answer (score 1):

Below code worked for me for Front facing camera.

```
if (data != null) {
                try {
                    int screenWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
                    int screenHeight = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
                    bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0,
                            (data != null) ? data.length : 0);
                    CameraInfo info = new CameraInfo();
                    Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraFace, info);
                    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
                        // Notice that width and height are reversed
                        // Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm,
                        // screenHeight, screenWidth, true);
                        // int w = scaled.getWidth();
                        // int h = scaled.getHeight();
                        // Setting post rotate to 90
                        Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
                        mtx.postRotate(90);
                        if (cameraFace == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT)
                            mtx.postRotate(180);
                        // Rotating Bitmap
                        bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(),
                                bm.getHeight(), mtx, true);
                    } else {// LANDSCAPE MODE
                        Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm,
                                screenWidth, screenHeight, true);
                        bm = scaled;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                } catch (Error e) {
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I tried the way in the answer, it works for back camera, for front camera, it need to rotate 270 not 90. :)