# Use camera in landscape when my app is in portrait

Tags: java, android, camera, screen-rotation

I've tried every way to accomplish my desired behaviour but nothing seems to work.

My app is **locked in portrait** mode (I don't want a landscape UI) but I want to be able to switch the camera  display to show a **camera preview in portrait and landscape** mode alternatively.

**I'm not interested in capturing images.**

To show the preview in portrait I simply do:

```
camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
```

and my preview works fine, but, when I try to show the camera preview in landscape mode, I do:

```
camera.setDisplayOrientation(0);
```

and the preview actually rotates, but the image from camera is not rotated, and the final result is just a portrait image rotated to landscape.

I've tried every way:

1) rotate the camera with `parameters.setRotation()` but this affects only the final image saved and has nothing to do with the preview;

2) set `parameters.set("orientation", "landscape")` but this seems to have no effect (maybe an old and not yet supported command?);

3) set every combination of the methods below, but nothing, the only way to effectively rotate the image originate from camera seems to be physically rotate my device…

This is a practical demonstration of what I mean:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see, `parameters.setRotation()` do **not have effect** on the preview, that is correct when is in portrait, but is simply rotate in landscape 'cause the camera don't rotate itself, but just place the portrait image rotated.

So, is there a way to show a camera preview in landscape when the app is in portrait?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16128608/camera-preview-is-in-portrait-mode-but-image-captured-is-rotated

Comment: @Alexandr yes, but as I say in my question, my problem it's not the final saved image (I'm not interested in capture image) but just the preview.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this method to set orientation of camera. The parameter `orientation` is Display.getRotation(), you could change set it as per your requirement.:

```
public void setCameraOrientation(int orientation) {
    int orientationDegree = 0;
    switch (orientation) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0:
            orientationDegree = 0;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_90:
            orientationDegree = 90;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_180:
            orientationDegree = 180;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_270:
            orientationDegree = 270;
            break;
    }
    int displayOrientation = (cameraInfo.orientation - orientationDegree + 360) % 360;
    camera.setDisplayOrientation(displayOrientation);
    Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
    parameters.setRotation(displayOrientation);
    camera.setParameters(parameters);
}
```

For the whole context check out my camera demo app [here](https://github.com/abdullah-chhatra/CameraApp). Specifically `CameraPreview` class.

Comment: **my app is locked in portrait**, and as I say in my **point 1**, `parameters.setRotation()` do not have effect on the preview image, just in the final capture. I've updated my question with practicals demonstrations.