# how to resolve the issue of rotation of bitmap image after capturing from camera

Tags: android

I created an android photo app in which I capture an image from camera and then draw that bitmap image on canvas in an another activity  but sometimes the bitmap image draw on canvas get rotated. How I can resolve this issue ? so that my app work smoothly.

Comment: can you please post your code ?

Comment: In this SO.Q. answers you will get answer too. [Camera Photo Orientation issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069122/camera-orientation-issue-in-android)

Comment: if ( exif != null ) {
   final int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt( ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1 ); if ( orientation != -1 ) {
    switch ( orientation ) {
    
     case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED:
      degree=90;
      break;
     case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
      degree = 90;
      break;
     case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
      degree = 180;
      break;
     case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
      degree = 270;
      break;
      
    }
   }
  }
  return degree;
 }

Comment: here I use this method

Comment: int oreintation=ex.getExifOrientation(imagepath);
try
{
ExifInterface exif=new ExifInterface(imagepath);
degree=ex.getExifOrientation(exif);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
System.out.println(e);
}
Matrix matrix =new Matrix();
//refresh_btn=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.refresh_view);
if(globalVariable.refresh==true)
{
degree=270;
globalVariable.refresh=false;
}
matrix.postRotate(degree);