# Capture image rotate after upload

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I am uploading image to server but image is rotate after uploaded to server Even preview is showing correct.

So many people facing this problem i found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069122/camera-orientation-issue-in-android) but didn't work. And there is many solution but i am not figure out how to fit in my code.

Please help me.

Here is my code

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.fonts.Text.MyTextView;
import com.generalClass.files.UploadFile;
import com.hwindiapp.driver.db.sqLite.DBConnect;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AddVehicleDocActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int FILE_SELECT_CODE = 124;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;

    TextView text_header;
    MyTextView insuranceHTxt;
    MyTextView permitHTxt;
    MyTextView vRegHTxt;
    MyTextView insNotFoundTxt;
    MyTextView permitNotFoundTxt;
    MyTextView vRegNotFoundTxt;
    DBConnect dbConnect;

    Button insBtn;
    Button permitBtn;
    Button vRegBtn;

    LinearLayout insImgVIew;
    LinearLayout permitImgVIew;
    LinearLayout vRegImgVIew;

    String language_labels_get_frm_sqLite = "";

    String LBL_DOCUMENTS_TXT_str = "";
    String LBL_YOUR_INSURANCE_TXT_str = "";
    String LBL_WRONG_FILE_SELECTED_TXT_str = "";
    String LBL_LOADING_TXT_str = "";
    String LBL_YOUR_PERMIT_TXT_str = "";
    String LBL_VEHICLE_REG_TXT_str = "";
    String LBL_NOT_FOUND_TXT_str = "";
    String LBL_BTN_OK_TXT_str = "";
    String LBL_ERROR_TXT_str = "";
    String LBL_TRY_AGAIN_LATER_TXT_str = "";
    String LBL_DOC_UPLOAD_SUCCESS_TXT_str = "";
    String LBL_ADD_TXT_str = "";
    String LBL_EDIT_TXT_str = "";
    String LBL_SUCCESS_TXT_str = "";
    String LBL_BTN_TRIP_CANCEL_CONFIRM_TXT_str = "";
    String LBL_NOTE_UPLOAD_DOC_TXT_str = "";
    String LBL_CANCEL_TXT_str = "";

    String currentDocType = "";

    String carJson_str = "";

    String vIns = "";
    String vPermit = "";
    String vReg = "";

    android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog alertDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_vehicle_doc);

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

        dbConnect = new DBConnect(this, "UC_Partner_Labels.db");
        text_header = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_header);
        insuranceHTxt = (MyTextView) findViewById(R.id.insuranceHTxt);
        permitHTxt = (MyTextView) findViewById(R.id.permitHTxt);
        vRegHTxt = (MyTextView) findViewById(R.id.vRegHTxt);
        insNotFoundTxt = (MyTextView) findViewById(R.id.insNotFoundTxt);
        permitNotFoundTxt = (MyTextView) findViewById(R.id.permitNotFoundTxt);
        vRegNotFoundTxt = (MyTextView) findViewById(R.id.vRegNotFoundTxt);

        insImgVIew = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.insImgArea);
        permitImgVIew = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.permitImgArea);
        vRegImgVIew = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.vRegImgArea);

        insBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.insBtn);
        permitBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.permitBtn);
        vRegBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.vRegBtn);

        insBtn.setOnClickListener(new setOnClickAct());
        permitBtn.setOnClickListener(new setOnClickAct());
        vRegBtn.setOnClickListener(new setOnClickAct());
        insImgVIew.setOnClickListener(new setOnClickAct());
        permitImgVIew.setOnClickListener(new setOnClickAct());
        vRegImgVIew.setOnClickListener(new setOnClickAct());

        carJson_str = getIntent().getStringExtra("CarJson");

        /* Set Labels */
        getLanguageLabelsFrmSqLite();
        /* Set Labels Finished */

        ImageView back_navigation = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.back_navigation);
        back_navigation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                AddVehicleDocActivity.super.onBackPressed();
            }
        });

        Log.d("carJson_str", ":" + carJson_str);

        try {
            parseCarJson(carJson_str);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void getLanguageLabelsFrmSqLite() {

        Cursor cursor = dbConnect.execQuery("select vValue from labels WHERE vLabel=\"Language_labels\"");

        cursor.moveToPosition(0);

        language_labels_get_frm_sqLite = cursor.getString(0);

        JSONObject obj_language_labels = null;
        try {
            obj_language_labels = new JSONObject(language_labels_get_frm_sqLite);
            LBL_DOCUMENTS_TXT_str = obj_language_labels.getString("LBL_DOCUMENTS_TXT");
            LBL_YOUR_INSURANCE_TXT_str = obj_language_labels.getString("LBL_YOUR_INSURANCE_TXT");
            LBL_WRONG_FILE_SELECTED_TXT_str = obj_language_labels.getString("LBL_WRONG_FILE_SELECTED_TXT");
            LBL_LOADING_TXT_str = obj_language_labels.getString("LBL_LOADING_TXT");
            LBL_YOUR_PERMIT_TXT_str = obj_language_labels.getString("LBL_YOUR_PERMIT_TXT");
            LBL_VEHICLE_REG_TXT_str = obj_language_labels.getString("LBL_VEHICLE_REG_TXT");
            LBL_NOT_FOUND_TXT_str = obj_language_labels.getString("LBL_NOT_FOUND_TXT");
            LBL_BTN_OK_TXT_str = obj_language_labels.getString("LBL_BTN_OK_TXT");
            LBL_ERROR_TXT_str = obj_language_labels.getString("LBL_ERROR_TXT");
            LBL_TRY_AGAIN_LATER_TXT_str = obj_language_labels.getString("LBL_TRY_AGAIN_LATER_TXT");
            LBL_DOC_UPLOAD_SUCCESS_TXT_str = obj_language_labels.getString("LBL_DOC_UPLOAD_SUCCESS_TXT");
            LBL_ADD_TXT_str = obj_language_labels.getString("LBL_ADD_TXT");
            LBL_EDIT_TXT_str = obj_language_labels.getString("LBL_EDIT_TXT");
            LBL_SUCCESS_TXT_str = obj_language_labels.getString("LBL_SUCCESS_TXT");
            LBL_BTN_TRIP_CANCEL_CONFIRM_TXT_str = obj_language_labels.getString("LBL_BTN_TRIP_CANCEL_CONFIRM_TXT");
            LBL_NOTE_UPLOAD_DOC_TXT_str = obj_language_labels.getString("LBL_NOTE_UPLOAD_DOC_TXT");
            LBL_CANCEL_TXT_str = obj_language_labels.getString("LBL_CANCEL_TXT");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (obj_language_labels != null) {
            text_header.setText("" + LBL_DOCUMENTS_TXT_str);
            insuranceHTxt.setText("" + LBL_YOUR_INSURANCE_TXT_str);
            permitHTxt.setText("" + LBL_YOUR_PERMIT_TXT_str);
            vRegHTxt.setText("" + LBL_VEHICLE_REG_TXT_str);
            insNotFoundTxt.setText("" + LBL_NOT_FOUND_TXT_str);
            permitNotFoundTxt.setText("" + LBL_NOT_FOUND_TXT_str);
            vRegNotFoundTxt.setText("" + LBL_NOT_FOUND_TXT_str);

            insBtn.setText(LBL_ADD_TXT_str);
            permitBtn.setText(LBL_ADD_TXT_str);
            vRegBtn.setText(LBL_ADD_TXT_str);
        }

    }

    public void parseCarJson(String carJson) throws JSONException {

        JSONObject obj_profile = new JSONObject(carJson);

        vIns = obj_profile.getString("vInsurance");
        vPermit = obj_profile.getString("vPermit");
        vReg = obj_profile.getString("vRegisteration");

        if (vIns == null || vIns.equals("")) {
            insNotFoundTxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            setDocView(0);
        }

        if (vPermit == null || vPermit.equals("")) {
            permitNotFoundTxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            setDocView(1);
        }

        if (vReg == null || vReg.equals("")) {
            vRegNotFoundTxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            setDocView(2);
        }
    }

    public void setDocView(int id) {
        if (id == 0) {
            insNotFoundTxt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            insBtn.setText(LBL_EDIT_TXT_str);
            insImgVIew.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        } else if (id == 1) {
            permitNotFoundTxt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            permitBtn.setText(LBL_EDIT_TXT_str);
            permitImgVIew.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        } else if (id == 2) {
            vRegNotFoundTxt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            vRegBtn.setText(LBL_EDIT_TXT_str);
            vRegImgVIew.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    public class setOnClickAct implements View.OnClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.insBtn:
                    currentDocType = "vInsurance";
                    chooseFIle();
                    break;

                case R.id.permitBtn:
                    currentDocType = "vPermit";
                    chooseFIle();
                    break;

                case R.id.vRegBtn:
                    currentDocType = "vRegisteration";
                    chooseFIle();
                    break;

                case R.id.insImgArea:
                    openDocument(vIns);
                    break;

                case R.id.permitImgArea:
                    openDocument(vPermit);
                    break;

                case R.id.vRegImgArea:
                    openDocument(vReg);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void openDocument(String documentName) {
        Log.d("Open doc","::"+CommonUtilities.SERVER_URL_VEHICLE_DOCS + getIntent().getStringExtra("iDriverVehicleId") + "/" + documentName);
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(CommonUtilities.SERVER_URL_VEHICLE_DOCS + getIntent().getStringExtra("iDriverVehicleId") + "/" + documentName));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
    }

    public void chooseFIle() {
        boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;
        if (isKitKat) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("*/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(intent, FILE_SELECT_CODE);

        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("*/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, FILE_SELECT_CODE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            if (requestCode == FILE_SELECT_CODE) {
                Uri uri = data.getData();

//                Log.d("Path", "::" + uri.getPath());
//                Log.d("Path", "::" + getPath(uri));

                String filePath = "";

                filePath = (getPath(uri) == null) ? uri.getPath() : getPath(uri);

//                Log.d("Ext", ":" + getFileExt(filePath));

                final ArrayList<String[]> paramsList = new ArrayList<>();
                paramsList.add(generateImageParams("iDriverVehicleId", "" + getIntent().getStringExtra("iDriverVehicleId")));
                paramsList.add(generateImageParams("type", "UploadVehicleDoc"));
                paramsList.add(generateImageParams("iDriverId", getIntent().getStringExtra("UserID")));
                paramsList.add(generateImageParams("DocUploadType", currentDocType));

                if (getFileExt(filePath).equalsIgnoreCase("jpg") || getFileExt(filePath).equalsIgnoreCase("gif") || getFileExt(filePath).equalsIgnoreCase("png")
                        || getFileExt(filePath).equalsIgnoreCase("jpeg") || getFileExt(filePath).equalsIgnoreCase("bmp") || getFileExt(filePath).equalsIgnoreCase("pdf")
                        || getFileExt(filePath).equalsIgnoreCase("doc") || getFileExt(filePath).equalsIgnoreCase("docx")) {


                    File selectedFile = new File(filePath);

                    if (selectedFile != null) {
                        android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(
                                AddVehicleDocActivity.this);

                        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(LBL_BTN_TRIP_CANCEL_CONFIRM_TXT_str);

                        final String finalFilePath = filePath;
                        alertDialogBuilder
                                .setMessage(selectedFile.getName() + "\n" + LBL_NOTE_UPLOAD_DOC_TXT_str)
                                .setCancelable(true)
                                .setNegativeButton(LBL_CANCEL_TXT_str, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                        alertDialog.dismiss();
                                    }
                                })
                                .setPositiveButton(LBL_BTN_OK_TXT_str, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        alertDialog.dismiss();
                                        new uploadDocument(finalFilePath, currentDocType + "." + getFileExt(finalFilePath), paramsList).execute();
                                    }
                                });
                        alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                        alertDialog.show();
                    } else {
                        showMessage(LBL_ERROR_TXT_str, LBL_TRY_AGAIN_LATER_TXT_str);
                    }
                } else {
//                    showErrorOnSelection();
                    showMessage(LBL_ERROR_TXT_str, LBL_WRONG_FILE_SELECTED_TXT_str);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public String[] generateImageParams(String key, String content) {
        String[] tempArr = new String[2];
        tempArr[0] = key;
        tempArr[1] = content;

        return tempArr;
    }

    public class uploadDocument extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        String selectedPath;
        String responseString = "";
        ProgressDialog myPDialog;

        String temp_File_Name = "";
        ArrayList<String[]> paramsList;

        public uploadDocument(String selectedPath, String temp_File_Name, ArrayList<String[]> paramsList) {
            this.selectedPath = selectedPath;
            this.temp_File_Name = temp_File_Name;
            this.paramsList = paramsList;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            myPDialog = new ProgressDialog(AddVehicleDocActivity.this, R.style.DialogTheme_custom);
            myPDialog.setMessage("" + LBL_LOADING_TXT_str);
            myPDialog.setCancelable(false);
            myPDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            myPDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

            responseString = new UploadFile().uploadImageAsFile(selectedPath, temp_File_Name, "vFile", paramsList);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            myPDialog.dismiss();

            Log.d("responseString", "::" + responseString);
            if (responseString != null && !responseString.equals("")) {

                try {
                    JSONObject obj_temp = new JSONObject(responseString);
                    String action_str = obj_temp.getString("Action");
                    String fileName_str = obj_temp.getString("vFileName");

                    if (action_str.equals("1")) {
                        showMessage(LBL_SUCCESS_TXT_str, LBL_DOC_UPLOAD_SUCCESS_TXT_str);

                        JSONObject obj_CarJson = new JSONObject(carJson_str);
                        if (currentDocType.equals("vInsurance")) {
                            obj_CarJson.remove("vInsurance");
                            obj_CarJson.put("vInsurance", fileName_str);
                            vIns = fileName_str;
                            setDocView(0);
                        } else if (currentDocType.equals("vPermit")) {
                            obj_CarJson.remove("vPermit");
                            obj_CarJson.put("vPermit", fileName_str);
                            vPermit = fileName_str;
                            setDocView(1);
                        } else if (currentDocType.equals("vRegisteration")) {
                            obj_CarJson.remove("vRegisteration");
                            obj_CarJson.put("vRegisteration", fileName_str);
                            vReg = fileName_str;
                            setDocView(2);
                        }
                        obj_CarJson.remove("eStatus");
                        obj_CarJson.put("eStatus", "Inactive");

                        carJson_str = obj_CarJson.toString();

                        Intent setData = new Intent();
                        setData.putExtra("CarJson", carJson_str);
                        setData.putExtra("DriverProfileData", obj_temp.getString("DriverProfileData").toString());
                        setData.putExtra("iDriverVehicleId", "" + getIntent().getStringExtra("iDriverVehicleId"));
                        setResult(RESULT_OK, setData);
//                        Driver_main_profile.updated_json_responseString_profile = obj_profileJson.toString();
//
//                        Driver_main_profile.driverDocUpdated = true;

                    } else {
                        showMessage(LBL_ERROR_TXT_str, LBL_TRY_AGAIN_LATER_TXT_str);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    showMessage(LBL_ERROR_TXT_str, LBL_TRY_AGAIN_LATER_TXT_str);
                }


            } else {
                showMessage(LBL_ERROR_TXT_str, LBL_TRY_AGAIN_LATER_TXT_str);
            }
        }
    }

    public String getFileExt(String fileName) {
        return fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1, fileName.length());
    }

    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            return filePath;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void showMessage(String title_str, String content_str) {
        android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(
                AddVehicleDocActivity.this);

        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(title_str);
        alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage(content_str)
                .setCancelable(true)
                .setPositiveButton(LBL_BTN_OK_TXT_str, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        alertDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();

    }
}
```

Here is my Upload code

```
 public class UploadFile {

    public String uploadImageAsFile(String sourceFileUri, String fileName, String imageParamKey, ArrayList<String[]> params) {


        ExifInterface exif = null;     //Since API Level 5
        try {
            exif = new ExifInterface(sourceFileUri);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String exifImage = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION);
        String responseString = "";
        InputStream inputStream;

        try {
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(exifImage));
            byte[] data;
            try {
                data = convertToByteArray(inputStream);

                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(CommonUtilities.SERVER_URL);

                InputStreamBody inputStreamBody = new InputStreamBody(new ByteArrayInputStream(data), fileName);
                MultipartEntity multipartEntity = new MultipartEntity(/*HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE,"9999999999", Charset.defaultCharset()*/);


                for (int i = 0; i < params.size(); i++) {
                    String[] paramsArr = params.get(i);
                    multipartEntity.addPart(paramsArr[0], new StringBody(paramsArr[1]));
                }

                ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(new File(exifImage)/*, "multipart/form-data"*/);
                multipartEntity.addPart(imageParamKey, cbFile);

                httpPost.setEntity(multipartEntity);

//                httpClient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USER_AGENT, "Test Browser");
//                httpClient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
//                httpClient.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.COOKIE_POLICY, org.apache.http.client.params.CookiePolicy.BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY);
//                httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
//                httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "image/png");
//                httpPost.setHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
//                httpPost.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
//                httpPost.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
//                httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;charset=UTF-8;boundary=654654");
//                httpPost.setHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
//                httpPost.setHeader("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");


                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                // Handle response back from script.
                if (httpResponse != null) {

                    Log.d("success", "success:" + httpResponse.toString());
                    responseString = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());

                } else { // Error, no response.

                    Log.d("Failed", "failed:" + httpResponse.toString());
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        return responseString;
    }

    private byte[] convertToByteArray(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {

        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        int next = inputStream.read();
        while (next > -1) {
            bos.write(next);
            next = inputStream.read();
        }

        bos.flush();

        return bos.toByteArray();
    }

    /**
     * @param encodedString
     * @return bitmap (from given string)
     */
    public Bitmap StringToBitMap(String encodedString){
        try{
            byte [] encodeByte=Base64.decode(encodedString, Base64.DEFAULT);
            Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);
            return bitmap;
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.getMessage();
            return null;
        }
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't rotate the image after upload. You need to rotate it before. The preview is correct maybe because you're respecting Exif values when showing it. But the server isn't.

You need to rotate the image according to it's exif rotation:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20480741/3410697

And only then you should upload it to the server

Comment: Try this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/11081918/3410697. The concept is simple, you need to rotate the image using exif values.

Answer (score 0):

Call this function where you get path of image

```
public void setImage(String _path) {
    int orientation = CustomImageUtil.getExifOrientation(_path);
    BitmapFactory.Options resample = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    resample.inSampleSize = 4;
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_path, resample);
    if (orientation == 90) {
        bitmap = CustomImageUtil.rotate(bitmap, 90);
    } else if (orientation == 180) {
        bitmap = CustomImageUtil.rotate(bitmap, 180);
    } else if (orientation == 270) {
        bitmap = CustomImageUtil.rotate(bitmap, 270);
    }

    // use your bitmap here


}
```

CustomImageUtil.class:

```
 public class CustomImageUtil {



public static  String getRealPathFromURI(Context context,Uri contentURI) {
    String result;
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) { // Source is Dropbox or other similar local file path
        result = contentURI.getPath();
    } else { 
        cursor.moveToFirst(); 
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA); 
        result = cursor.getString(idx);
        cursor.close();
    }
    return result;
}

// method for bitmap to base64
public static String encodeTobase64(Bitmap image) {
    Bitmap immage = image;
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    immage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 60, baos);
    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
    String imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);

    Log.d("Image Log:", imageEncoded);
    return imageEncoded;



}

/**
 * getExifOrientation -- Roate the image on the right angel
 * @param filepath -- path of the file to be rotated
 * @return
 */
public static int getExifOrientation(String filepath) {

    int degree = 0;
    ExifInterface exif = null;
    try {
        exif = new ExifInterface(filepath);
    } catch (IOException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (exif != null) {
        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, -1);
        if (orientation != -1) {
            // We only recognize a subset of orientation tag values.
            switch (orientation) {
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                    degree = 90;
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                    degree = 180;
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                    degree = 270;
                    break;
            }

        }
    }
    return degree;
}



// Rotates the bitmap by the specified degree.
// If a new bitmap is created, the original bitmap is recycled.
public static Bitmap rotate(Bitmap b, int degrees) {
    if (degrees != 0 && b != null) {
        Matrix m = new Matrix();
        m.setRotate(degrees, (float) b.getWidth() / 2,
                (float) b.getHeight() / 2);
        try {
            Bitmap b2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(b, 0, 0, b.getWidth(),
                    b.getHeight(), m, true);
            if (b != b2) {
                b.recycle();
                b = b2;
            }
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError ex) {ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return b;
}


 }
```

To convert Bitmap to Uri

```
public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
String path = Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

Comment: this method return the bitmap but i want the string so can i convert bitmap to string??

Comment: post a function to convert bitmap to URI

Comment: i have this function but facing same problem.

Comment: URI can convert to string by using .toSting()